# Find the unknown element "c3" value in a triangle of dependent integers

Tags: python, arrays, list, tree

I have a triangle with four integer values at the top between 1 to 256. The values below it are all determined by the "distance" between the two values immediately above them. That distance is the subtraction of the left-hand "parent" from the right-hand parent, plus 1. It this result would be 0 or negative, then 256 is added to the result, so it is guaranteed to be between 1 and 256.

#### Example

```
49      52      158    201
  \   /    \    /  \  /   
    4       107     44
     \     /   \   /
       104      194
          \    /           
            91
```

#### Explanation

The top row is the input. The other rows are derived:

The second row starts with 52 - 49 + 1 = 4, then follows 158 - 52 + 1 = 107, ...etc.

The second value in the third row needs the additional 256: it is 44 - 107 + 1 + 256 = 194

## The actual challenge

For the actual challenge, we don't have the third input value, but instead the final value at the bottom, and we need to find out what the third value should be. Also, the range of the values is not always 1..256, but 1..Variable<sup>No_In_1_Group</sup>, where these are inputs too. In the above example, `Variable = 2` and `No_In_1_Group = 8`

So we have this pattern:

```
c1    c2    c3    c4   
  \  /  \  /  \  /
   f1    f2    f3        (f: first level distance)
     \  /  \  /
      s1    s2           (s: second level distance)
        \  /
         t1              (t: third level distance)
```

Given input: `Variable, No_In_1_Group, c1, c2, c4, t1`

Required output: `c3`

#### For Example:

Input: `c1 = 49, c2 = 52, c4 = 201, t1 = 91, Variable = 2, No_In_1_Group = 8`

Output: `c3 = 158`

```
49    52    ?    201
  \  /  \  / \  /   
    .     .    .
     \  /   \ /
       .     .
        \   /           
          91
```

### Attempt

I have a function `Distance_Calculation`:

```
def Distance_Calculation(Variable, No_In_1_Group, Comb_1, Comb_2):
"""This function gives the value of "*Direct_Distance*" if Comb_1 & Comb_2 are known."""
    if (Comb_2 >= Comb_1):
        return Comb_2 - Comb_1 + 1
    else:
        return pow(Variable, No_In_1_Group) - Comb_1 + Comb_2 + 1
```

So I could call it like this, provided I already gave the values of the arguments:

```
f1 = Distance_Calculation(Variable, No_In_1_Group, c1, c2) or 
s2 = Distance_Calculation(Variable, No_In_1_Group, f2, f3) or
t1 = Distance_Calculation(Variable, No_In_1_Group, s1, s2)
```

But I would need sometimes to derive a sibling value from a child value. For that I have this function:

```
"""If Comb_1 & Direct_Distance are known, then Comb_2 will be calculated using this function"""
def Reverse_Distance_Calculation(Variable, No_In_1_Group, Comb_1, Direct_Distance):
    if (Comb_1+Direct_Distance-pow(Variable, No_In_1_Group)-1 <= 0 and Direct_Distance-1 >= 0):
        return Comb_1 + Direct_Distance - 1
    else:
        return Comb_1 + Direct_Distance - pow(Variable, No_In_1_Group) - 1
```

In a similar fashion, all `f` and `s` values are calculated with the following code:

```
def get_unknown_element(c1, c2, c4_final, t1_final):
    c4 = c4_final
    base_reminder_index = Variable**No_In_1_Group
    for i in range(1,base_reminder_index+1):
        c3 = i
        f1 = Distance_Calculation(Variable, No_In_1_Group, c1, c2)
        f2 = Distance_Calculation(Variable, No_In_1_Group, c2, c3)
        f3 = Distance_Calculation(Variable, No_In_1_Group, c3, c4)
        s1 = Distance_Calculation(Variable, No_In_1_Group, fld1, fld2)
        s2 = Distance_Calculation(Variable, No_In_1_Group, fld2, fld3)
        t1 = Distance_Calculation(Variable, No_In_1_Group, sld1, sld2)
        if (t1 == t1_final):
            return i
    return -1
```

## Problem and question

The above method is not very efficient as it takes a max of 256 iterations in every single run and I have run this code more than 1000 times to get my desired result. Is there an efficient method where iterations can be reduced drastically?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the logic but I think that in the example you linked, t1 should be 41 instead of 91?

Comment: @SiP, in the above example, s1 = 104 & s2 = 194, and using the distance function, we can get the value of t1 = 194 - 104 + 1 = 91. How did you calculate t1 = 41?

Comment: the 194 should be 64...

Comment: Ok, understand this in detail. c1 = 49, c2 = 52, c4 = 201 & t1 = 91. Assume c3 as 158. Now -:
f1 = 52 -  49 + 1 = 4 (as c2 > c1), 
f2 = 158 - 52 + 1 = 107 (as c3 > c2)
f3 = 201 - 158 + 1 = 44 (as c4 > c3)
s1 = 107 - 4 + 1 = 104 (as f2 > f1)
***s2 = 256 + 44 - 107 + 1 = 194(as f3 < f2)
t1 = 194 - 104 + 1 = 91 (as s2 > s1)
Hope this will clarify. All the greater or lesser conditions have been taken from the distance formulae mentioned in the question. So, 158 is the correct value of c3 as final t1 value is matched with our calculate t1 value.

Comment: if f2=107 and f3=44 then s2 = 107-44+1=64. no?

Comment: A repost of [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76005049/find-the-value-of-unknown-element-c3-in-the-given-arrangement-of-elements?noredirect=1#comment134050288_76005049) with a different user account?

Comment: @SiP, if f2=107 and f3=44, then s2 = 256 + 44 - 107 + 1 = 194 (as f3 < f2). Mentioned in the distance formulae. What you mentioned would have been the case if f3 > f2.

Comment: Try to formulate the question in such a way that it is self-explanatory. I see you have added here a comment with a worked out example. That would be actually be useful to see in your question.

Comment: @tricot, yeah I agree that articulation could be better. My bad! But, do you have any comments regarding the solution? If yes, please do let me know as I am in need of solution. I work as Product Manager and my coding skills are limited.

Comment: Did a revamp on your question -- please check if this corresponds to your intention. (upvoted)

Comment: @trincot, revamp looks amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first consider `Variable` and `No_In_1_Group` as one input `m`, like `m=256` in your example.

The calculation adds 256 (ie. the value `m`) when a result would become negative. This corresponds to [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). When c2 would be less than c1 or equal), we should get `m + (c2 - c1 + 1)`, but that is `c2 - c1 (mod m)  + 1`, which in Python you get with the modulo operator: `(c2 - c1) % m + 1`. The `+ 1` is left out of the modulo operation as you don't values in the range `0..m-1`, but `1..m`

The calculation can be expanded from top to bottom as follows, always considering that the expressions are to be considered modulo `m` (as explained above):

```
c1           c2           c3           c4
  \         /  \         /  \         /
   (c2-c1+1)    (c3-c2+1)    (c4-c3+1)
       \           / \           /
        (c3-2c2+c1)   (c4-2c3+c2)
           \                 /
            (c4-3c3+3c2-c1+1)
```

The bottom expression must equal `t1 - 1 (mod m) + 1`, so to rewrite that in terms of c3 (the unknown):

```
3c3 = c4 + 3c2 - c1 - t1 (mod m) + 1
```

Because of the coefficient 3 at the left side we actually have 3 candidates to solve this equation:

```
c3 =    [c4 + 3c2 - c1 - t1 (mod m) + 1] / 3
 or     [c4 + 3c2 - c1 - t1 (mod m) + 1 + m] / 3
 or     [c4 + 3c2 - c1 - t1 (mod m) + 1 + 2m] / 3
```

To rewrite this in Python:

```
def solve (c1, c2, c4, t1, m):
    triple_c3 = (c4 + 3*c2 - c1 - t1) % m + 1
    if triple_c3 % 3:
        triple_c3 += m
        if triple_c3 % 3:
            triple_c3 += m
            if triple_c3 % 3:
                return None  # No solution
    return (triple_c3 // 3 - 1) % m + 1  # map to 1..m range

c3 = solve(49, 52, 201, 91, 256)

print(c3)  # 158
```

Comment: f1 = c2 - c1 + 1 only if c2>c1 otherwise it would be 256 + c2 - c1 + 1, so 2 values for f1 needs to be considered.

Comment: Yes, but that is modular arithmetic, no?

Comment: Modular arithmetic means?

Comment: Added explanation at the top of my answer.

Comment: Reasonable explanation and great answer too! Thanks man!

Comment: Hi @trincot, could you please help me with this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76532708/find-the-combination-of-coin-chips-by-minimising-the-value-of-e-4n-0-3n